# How to scale an image to show as a background image on android tablet and portrait mode

Tags: android, picasso

Below is my screen design for MainActivity

```
|Top Navigation Bar  
|Content Area
|Bottom Navigation Bar
```

I want to show a background image in the content area. which fill the entire content area

I'm getting the background image from the server below is my JSON Response, if the device is Phone or tablet I picked the phonePortrait or tabletPortrait image to show a background image.if the device is landscape use tabletLandscape image. this response is used by Android and IOS app both.

```
{ 
 meta: {
  timeToCache: 5
 },
 body: {
  ....
  title: "LIVE this week",
  description: "NBA",
  phonePortrait: "https://xyx.com.au/home-nba-r1.jpg",
  tabletPortrait: "https://xyx.com.au//home-nba-r2.jpg",
  tabletLandscape: "https://xyx.com.au/home-nba-r3.jpg",
  phoneSmallPortrait: "https://xyx.com.au/home-nba-r4.jpg",
  ....
 }
}
```

I used Picasso library to load the image into the backroind imageView

```
   Picasso.with(getContext())
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .fit()
                    .into(back_img);
```

Layout File

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_template_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="89dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back_img"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_description"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"/>
....

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But the problem is image is not showing properly (image stretch or cut the top part), What's the best way to keep the aspect ratio of the image and show as background image for all the android screen sizes

a) Do I need to introduce multiple images for mdpi/hdpi/xhpdi/xxhdpi for portrait mode and for landscape mode if so what should be the image sizes?

b) is there any other way I can use a single image to work in all portrait mode and single image to work in landscape mode

c) I tried with below code but still, image is not properly showing

```
/* DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();


getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        int toolBarHeight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar).getHeight();
        int bottomBarHeight  = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tabs).getHeight();

        int viewPortHeight = screenHeight - (toolBarHeight + bottomBarHeight);

        Picasso
                .with(getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                //.resize(screenWidth,viewPortHeight) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
                .fit()
                .centerInside()
                .into(parent_home_template_back_img);*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

in your `ImageView`

See [ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for more

Comment: Do i need to change anything in Picasso call ?

Comment: @Sam I think you don't need to change

Comment: no luck adding scaleType-"fitxy", still image is stretched

Comment: @Sam its not possible to do that.  Server will need to send exact size of image depending on your screen size.  You can only control the image view not the image.  Because if the server sends a very small image it will have to stretch to fit or it will appear small if you do wrap content

Comment: "You can only control the image view not the image" I thought running Picasso  .fit() method actually scaling the image to fit on the imageView.

Comment: so what should be the best approach and what sort if image sizes I need to upload to server?

Comment: @Sam yes it may stretch while scaling